# Javascript - how to made constructor with config values?

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs, constructor

I have searched plenty of javascript OOP libraries, but I found just one with the functionality I want. I want to create javascript object with config values like this :

var iPhone = new SmartPhone({
     hasTouchScreen: true,
     operatingSystem: 'iOS'
});

the only one library which I found is Sencha Ext JS4
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.ClassManager

...what is the magic of create constructor like this ? or could you suggest me any other OOP library which can do this for me ? I'm looking for free library, because I need this into our commercial application, so I cannot use free Sencha which is just for open source projects.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _config values_? How do they affect the actual created object? At the moment it just looks like you want to copy the properties of an object to your instance.

Comment: This is a very common concept... I feel like it is used by almost all libraries (including the library code I write myself).

Comment: `/*free library*/function SmartPhone(opts){this.hasTouchScreen = !!opts.hasTouchScreen;this.operatingSystem=opts.operatingSystem;}`

Comment: I´m just interested in how to create object to which I can pass values in constructor like this : new SmartPhone({ hasTouchScreen: true, operatingSystem: 'iOS' }) and not like this : new SmartPhone(true,'iOS')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic:

```
var SmartPhone = (function SmartPhoneClass() {

  function SmartPhone(props) {
    this.hasTouchScreen = props.hasTouchScreen || false;
    this.operatingSystem = props.operatingSystem || 'Android';
  }

  SmartPhone.prototype = {
    ...
  };

  return SmartPhone;

}());

var iPhone = new SmartPhone({
  hasTouchScreen: true,
  operatingSystem: 'iOS'
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you guys, this is what I was looking for :)